# How to purge the message from persistence Hivemq broker

Tags: hivemq

We are using HIVEMQ Mqtt broker 3.2.1 . We want to purge some persistence  Message . Please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To purge `persistentSessions`, reconnect the corresponding clients with the same `clientId` using `cleanSession=true`.

I hope this helps.